# Compare Products php script

Tags: php, mysql, json, pivot

mysql> SELECT spm_id, spec_value , product_name FROM test1.spec_property;

```
+--------+---------------------+----------------+
| spm_id | spec_value          |product_name    |
+--------+---------------------+----------------+
|      6 | Yellow Gold         |ring1           |
|      7 | 22                  |ring1           |
|      7 | 22                  |ring2           |
|      7 | 24                  |ring3           |
|     11 | girl                |ring1           |
+--------+---------------------+----------------+
```

Need Something Like This

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| spm_id | col1                | col 2               | col 3               |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|        | Ring1               | Ring 2              |Ring 3               |
|      6 | Yellow Gold         |                     |                     |
|      7 | 22                  | 22                  | 24                  |
|     11 | girl                |                     |                     |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Actually i need **product compare php script** in php for above table.  mostly am looking for php script which will provide compare products.

Answer (score 1):

The technical term for your requirement is a *pivot.* Doing pivots in pure MySQL is a notorious pain in the neck; there are ways you can look up.

In the meantime, you might try (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1a76/2/0)

```
SELECT spm_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(spec_value ORDER BY spec_value) vals
  FROM spec_property
 GROUP BY spm_id
```

This will give you a comma-separated list instead of separate columns. But if you need to turn the resultset into JSON, that should be workable.

You can even get MySQL to do some JSON-style formatting for you if need be: this will put the items in your list in double quotes. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1a76/4/0)

```
SELECT spm_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('"',spec_value,'"') ORDER BY spec_value) vals
  FROM spec_property
 GROUP BY spm_id
```

Comment: You might need to add escaping so the data can be unambiguously recovered.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. i need above result for product compare page. when i do group_concat, i can't able to split by product id